# Git : explore folders tructure of old commit without checking it out

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-ls-tree

I want to look at the folder structure of an old commit that I cannot checkout anymore (it had some Git LFS stuff which is now broken beyond my power to repair it).

I can already diff it to its parent and learn a lot, but I also want to see the contents of other folders and files (even if they weren't modified by that commit).

Comment: Your question is already tagged with `git-ls-tree`, a command that seems to be sufficient for your requirement. Just wondering, isn't `git-ls-tree` what you're looking for? Additionally, I believe tools like `tig` may be more convenient to peek deeper down to the history.

Comment: I just don't know how to use `ls-tree` properly it seems, I get errors in some cases. And it doesn't have to be that anyways, that's more of a suggestion, and I am open to more.

Comment: Also `tig` (which I am discovering as I speak is 1. slow in git bash on Windows and 2. Shows me a tree of the history on one half the screen and diffs with parent on the other. Could expand on how `tig` could help me with my original question ?

Comment: `git-ls-tree` allows you inspecting commit/tree content. Say, you do `git ls-tree <COMMIT>`, get a list of hashes for trees and blobs (= directories and files at _that_commit), and then use `git ls-tree <TREE_HASH>` to walk through trees untill you find the file you're interested in, and then do `git cat-file -p <BLOB_HASH>` to get the file content. I'm not sure how it works with LFS (have never worked with it, but I guess it's relevant to big blobs only), but if your commit is still reachable, then you can inspect the folder structure of the commits of your interest.

Comment: If you find `git-ls-tree` too tedious, `tig` (or any other appropriate tools, not necessarily `tig`, doing the same as I described above) allows you walking through trees. You see a two-pane log/diff view because you pressed `Enter`. Try pressing `t` at a certain commit (and `h` for quick help).

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `git ls-tree` and `git cat-file` to quickly show any file with part of a pattern.

In a Windows CMD:

`git ls-tree --full-tree -r @ | awk '/comm/ { cmd="git cat-file blob " $3; print "\n\n"$4"\n-------"; while ((cmd^|getline result)^>0) { print result }; close(cmd) }'`

In a git bash:

`git ls-tree --full-tree -r @ | awk '/comm/ { cmd="git cat-file blob " $3; print "\n\n"$4"\n-------"; while ((cmd|getline result)>0) { print result }; close(cmd) }'`

Replace '`comm`' with any part of the files you want to see.

Or use `awk '// ...'` to list *all* the files and display their content.